# How can I fix boot hang on 20.10?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I've reinstalled 20.10 six times now. Each time I try variations on the installation options. This time I overwrote entire disc and chose not to enable secure boot. After being prompted to remove my live usb and hit enter all I got was dark blue screen. I held power button to force shutdown. Grub appeared on restart, but selecting ubuntu os gave me another dark blue screen. I tried it again, and selected advanced options, then top choice of ubuntu os and it loaded. I installed recommended software updates then selected "restart now" when prompted and got nothing but dark blue screen again. I held power button to force shutdown again,grub wouldn't load. Did forced shutdown three times and then grub loaded. Selected advanced options then first ubuntu os and now it hangs on "loading linux 5.8.0-33 generic ... Ive been using Ubuntu for about 15 years and never had so much grief installing. Any solutions welcome.
Cheers

Comment: This may be a totally unrelated issue, but is your storage device okay? My hard drive that failed was having issues similar to this, and it was due to a *lot* of bad sectors on the drive that was just.. stopping the drive from running well.

Comment: Looks more like hardware or BIOS related as you're able to reach the end of installation process. Could you describe the steps you followed during installation?

Comment: Hardware info might be helpful

Comment: Thank you all for considering my question. This is an hp pavillion laptop. I have been dual booting versions of ubuntu with win 10 for the entire period. A couple weeks ago startup got glitchy

Comment: it hung up while loading, and I found I could sometimes get it to work bu using safe mode or just other iterations of the os in the grub menu. Finally I removed key files and upgraded to 20.10 leaving win10 in place as well. It worked fine for a few days, then begain hanging again. I tried boot repair and other options using terminal but nothing worked and I for all sorts of errors seemingly randomly each time I tried again.

Comment: Today I replaced hd with out of the box new samsung 860 evo and tried installing newly.made live usb with 20.04 but although I do get a grub menu on restart, it stiil remains a dark blue screen

Comment: latest installation steps were to connect to power and internet cable, plug in usb drive, turn on machine and press escape key, Select f-9, select  try ubuntu, open live session of ubuntu to see internet is functional, select install, Follow prompts and wait awhile. After installation I removed usb at the prompt and waited for restart. Nothing but dark blue for several minutes so I shut off and turned back on. Basic grub showed up but won't actually boot machine. I can select uefi and see bios and such